# Android: prevent sniffing (e.g. with CharlesProxy) of SSL traffic

Tags: android, ssl, charles-proxy

I use Charles to check what data is send throw my app to HTTPS. I installed the Charles CA cert on my phone and because of that, I'm able to decrypt every SSL traffic.

But I found apps, where I'm not possible to see the SSL traffic. How can I implement this behavior into my own app? With this, no man in the middle attack would be possible.

Comment: by properly verifying the server you're connected to: http://tersesystems.com/2014/03/23/fixing-hostname-verification/

Answer (score 6):

> ...I installed the Charles CA cert on my phone and because of that, I'm able to decrypt every SSL traffic.
>
> But I found apps, where I'm not possible to see the SSL traffic. How can I implement this behavior into my own app? With this, no man in the middle attack would be possible.

This can be done with certificate/public key pinning, where you don't check the servers certificate against the local root certificates, but instead make sure that you only get the expected certificate. See [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) for details and code samples.

Answer (score 6):

Certificate Pinning is what you are after, but be aware that doing so is not without its disadvantages and complications. Certificate pinning adds a layer of complexity to your system which means more work on deployment day and one more thing that can go wrong.

A classic mistake that is made with Certificate Pinning is that the backend team will update/change/tweak the server certificate when they release an update, and forget that the clients are using certificate pinning, which will basically bring your entire system to a halt.

The reason that the big boys use it is to disguise their api so that it is difficult for hackers/leechers to make uninvited calls into their backend.